# Multiple child relative position to parent in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a Background and two Clouds images.

I want to move them independently and I want be able to embed the code at any website.

I cannot get the clouds move in an absolute positioning mode, there is one of theme always relative to the other

html code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cloud-01" />
    <div id="cloud-02" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 281px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

#cloud-01
{
    background-image: url('images/cloud.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 80px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 102px;
}

#cloud-02
{
    background-image: url('images/cloud2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 90px;
    height: 47px;
    width: 114px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: div is not a self closing element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cloud-01" />
    <div id="cloud-02" />
</div>
```

is parsed as/"error corrected" into this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cloud-01">
        <div id="cloud-02"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you close the `div` elements properly, your CSS will work correctly:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cloud-01"></div>
    <div id="cloud-02"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are awesome guys! StackOverflow is awesome... :) I'm / was a Flex developer so I inherited this error.